# how to remove all elements in a python list which are less than a particular number of charecters

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, list, python-requests

How do you remove all elements in a list which are less than a particular number of characters? we have a list of 50 elements. I'm trying to remove all elements with less than 30 characters.
I tried using my_list.remove but it won't work.

The elements are strings and I'm trying to remove the number of elements with less than 20 characters or alphabets

Comment: Please read how to create a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Try using ``del``

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
filtered = filter(lambda x: len(x)>29, my_list)
filtered_list = list(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
example_list = ["1234", "12345", "123456", "1234567"]

# Example: Only keep list elements with over 5 characters
filtered_list = list(filter(lambda el: len(el) > 5, example_list))

print(filtered_list)
```

Output:

```py
['123456', '1234567']
```

To only keep elements with 30 or more elements, you would change `len(el) > 5` to either `len(el) > 29` or `len(el) >= 30`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
list1 = ['1', '2', '3' ...]
if len(list1)>50:
     number = len(list1)-50
     print(list1[number:])
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove elements while iterating, you have create a new list.

```
new_list = [x for x in old_list if len(x) > 30]
```

Even this will do, because right side is calculated first and then old value is overwritten:

```
old_list = [x for x in old_list if len(x) > 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
a = ["1", " 2", "123455"]
b = []
for i in a:
    if len(i)>50:
        b.append(i)
a= b
print(b)
```